# why I get this error with Python boto s3 select_object_content?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to run the following code in Windows to get the first few lines from an s3 object:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
sql_stmt = """select * from s3object limit 5"""

req = s3.select_object_content(
 Bucket=bucket,
 Key=file,
 ExpressionType='SQL',
 Expression=sql_stmt,
 InputSerialization = {'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'Use', 'FieldDelimiter': ','}},
 OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}})
```

It keeps telling me:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: 
S3 Transfer Acceleration is not configured on this bucket
```

This may be related to my trying to test out transfer acceleration earlier this year (it didn't work). I tried to confirm and disable the transfer acceleration with aws cli:

```
aws configure set default.s3.use_accelerate_endpoint false
```

I can run this same code from an EMR cluster so the error is definitely local my Windows environment. How can I disable transfer acceleration??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your boto3 application was launched using a non-default AWS profile (e.g. set through the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable or [some other supported way](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#guide-credentials)), or your `~/.aws/config` file is not correct.

If using the default profile, then I would check that `~/.aws/config` looks something like this:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
    use_accelerate_endpoint = false
```

Comment: Ah yes, I had an additional profile in there. I removed it and left the default. Thank you!!